# Decode URL in Json using TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript, urldecode

the API from BE returns a Json string and I parse that collection to Products[] which describe as below

```
class Products {
  ProductId: number;
  ProductName: string;
  Price: number;
  ProductUrl: string;
}
```

The problem is the ProductUrl string was encoded. So, how to auto decode the ProductUrl of class Products whenever I map the Json string to Products[]?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Encoded ***how***? Could we have an example of what it looks like and what that example should decode to? That's a really important detail to include in the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how the url is encoded, but maybe `decodeURI()` would do the trick.